# NullReferenceException singleton instance

Tags: c#, azureservicebus

I have the following code (the important bits):

```
while(true){
  BrokeredMessage message = subscriptionClient.Receive();

  if (message.Properties.ContainsKey("MessageType"))
  {
      try
      {
          SmsService.Instance.SendSms("lenio", user.PhoneNumber, SomeString);
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          throw;
      }
   }
}
```

The code runs continuously and the message I receive is handled and SomeString is just some string.

The SmsService class looks like this:

```
public class SmsService
{
    private const string Username = "******";
    private const string Password = "******";
    private static SmsService _instance = null;
    private static readonly Lazy<SmsService> lazy =
    new Lazy<SmsService>(() => new SmsService());


    private SmsService() { }

    public static SmsService Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return lazy.Value;
        }
    }

    public bool SendSms(string from, string receiver, string message)
    {
        string url = UrlBuilder(from, receiver, message);

        HttpWebRequest newRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        HttpStatusCode statusCode = new HttpStatusCode();

        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)newRequest.GetResponse();
            statusCode = response.StatusCode;
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            statusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode;
        }

        if (statusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            Logger.Instance.AddToLog(0, "SMS", "Sms Send to: +" + receiver);
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            Logger.Instance.AddToLog(0, "SMS", "Failed to send sms to: +" + receiver);

            return false;
        }

    }
    public string NewLine()
    {
        return "%0a";
    }

    private static string UrlBuilder(string from, string to, string message)
    {
        string newTo = "45" + to;
        string encodedMessage = message.Replace(" ", "+");
        string encodedfrom = from.Replace(" ", "+");

        return "http://sms.sms1290.dk/?username=" + Username + "&password=" + Password + "&to=" + newTo + "&from=" + encodedfrom + "&message=" + encodedMessage;
    }
}
```

I have a problem that sometimes, if I receive a lot of messages I get a "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." exception on SmsService. I sometimes also get an "operation timed out" on:

```
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)newRequest.GetResponse();
```

I have made a gist with more code if needed: https://gist.github.com/Niclassg/54b908fbf5cc9b3e11a7

Stacktrace on "operation timed out":

```
>   lenioServiceBus.exe!lenioServiceBus.SmsService.SendSms(string from, string receiver, string message) Line 44    C#
lenioServiceBus.exe!lenioServiceBus.Program.AlarmDeactivated(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage message) Line 489   C#
lenioServiceBus.exe!lenioServiceBus.Program.msgHandler(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage message) Line 109 C#
lenioServiceBus.exe!lenioServiceBus.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 59 C#
[External Code]
```

Line 44:

```
            catch (WebException we)
        {
            statusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode;  //<-- Line 44
        }
```

Line 489:

```
if (user.NotifyBySms)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Notify user : " + user.Name + " by phone on number: " +
                                      user.PhoneNumber);
                    string msg = "Alarmen i dit hus er nu deaktiveret. ";
                    SmsService.Instance.SendSms("lenio", user.PhoneNumber, msg);  //<-- Line 489
                    //Notify user! (alarm now deactive)
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Notify user: " + user.Name + "on smartphone");
                    //Notify user! (alarm now deactive)
                }
```

Line 59:

```
 if (msgHandler(message))  //<-- Line 59
            {
                Logger.Instance.SaveLog();
                try
                {
                    message.Complete();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //We  might have lost the lock on the message and were too slow to handle it! (Use RenewLock)
                }

            }
            else
            {
                Logger.Instance.SaveLog();

                message.Abandon();
            }
```

The operation timed out exception always follows with nullexception that has this stacktrace:

```
>   lenioServiceBus.exe!lenioServiceBus.Program.AlarmDeactivated(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage message) Line 507   C#
lenioServiceBus.exe!lenioServiceBus.Program.msgHandler(Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.BrokeredMessage message) Line 109 C#
lenioServiceBus.exe!lenioServiceBus.Program.Main(string[] args) Line 59 C#
[External Code]
```

Line 507:

```
catch (Exception ex) //the ex contains the "{"Object reference not set to an instance of an                   object."} exception
        {
            Logger.Instance.AddToLog(2, "AlarmDeactivate", "Failed to deactivate alarm on communicationdevice: " + message.Properties["cdId"] + " with exception: " + ex.Message); //<--Line 507
            return false;
        }
```

I found out I get this error if I send a message before the other message has completed. I need a solution for this.

Comment: Please show a full stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Can you tell us which line is line 44?

Comment: It is common error. Add breakpoint on 44 line and see whick object is null!!!

Comment: `((HttpWebResponse)we.Response)` is equal to null. You definitely sometimes not getting HttpWebResponse type in exception.Response. [Aaaand documentations is your really close friend.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webexception.response(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Okay so now we've established that we.Response is sometimes null and I fixed that part using Pete Scott's answer but I still need to be able to send multiple messages without the system does this.

Comment: So mark Petes answer as accepted and make another question, because it is another topic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the remote host did not return a response, then the we.Response on line 44 is null, so the attempt to read the StatusCode property will fail (with "object ref not set").

You will need to change your exception handling (line 44) to not always assume that the WebException has a Response.

Perhaps something like:

```
statusCode = HttpStatusCode.ServiceUnavailable; // set a default
...
try
{
    ...
}
catch (WebException we)
{
    if (we.Response != null)
    {
        statusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode;
    }
}
```

You say: "The operation timed out exception always follows with nullexception that has this stacktrace"

The service you are communicating with is limited to processing one request at a time. Whether intentional or not, you probably cannot do anything to "fix" that. My best thought at this time would be a simple lock around the communication in the SendSms() method, so that you only allow one request to communicate at a time. This will probably introduce scalability issues, but would certainly be better than simply failing.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That solves the exception but I still have the problem that I cannot send a message to the service-bus before the current message has been completed and that defeats the purpose. Any solutions to that?